# Регистрация на сайте используя HttpURLConnection в android

Tags: android, веб-программирование, forms, httpurlconnection

На сайте имеется следующая форма (поменять форму нет возможности):

```
<form method="post" action="/login.pl" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="login_form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td">Логин:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user"  maxlength="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td">Пароль:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td />
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="//site.ru/index.pl"/>
</form>
```

Используя HttpURLConnection, отправляю multipartr POST запрос. Контролирую отсылку запроса с помощью WireShark. Отправляется не один, а три запроса. В результате авторизации не происходит. Если же, делаю запрос через telnet на 80 порт, то все нормально, получаю, к примеру Cookie: SID=8908925884138574, что мне и требуется.

Comment: код где? или мультипарт отправляется силой мысли?